# getcontentresolver().insert always returns null in android 4.4 and above devices

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-4.4-kitkat, android-contentresolver, ringtone

iam trying to set ringtone programmatically using below code. It is working fine in jelly bean devices but it was not working in Kitkat devices. i always getting newUri as null.

```
    private void SetAsRingtone(String filepath) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "test");
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringtoneFile.length());
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "artist");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
    Log.i("RingtonesAdapter", "the absolute path of the file is :"+ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
      context.getContentResolver().delete(
               uri,
               MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                       + ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);

    try{
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);
    Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.RINGTONE, newUri.toString());       

       } catch (Throwable t) {

       }
}
```

below is my file path and uri

filepath : /storage/emulated/0/audiofiles/MUSIC_19.mp3
Uri : content://media/external/audio/media

i also had "WRITE_SETTINGS" permission included in manifest

Please some one let me know where iam doing wrong. Do i need to add any other permissions ?

Comment: i tested again and again and observed the followingi tested again and again and observed the following 1) Randomly i am getting newUri but most of the times it is returning null. 2) Whenever the id value at the end of newUri is less than 200, ringtone is not getting set(//media/external/audio/media/133) .3) Folder which i am storing the audio files is a hidden folder (dot in front of folder name) , when i changed my folder from hidden , i didn't got null value for newUri and every time the ringtone got set. But the hidden folder is not an issue in jelly bean devices

Comment: i resolved the issue.. Can someone tell me how to close this question ?

Comment: I am Having the same problem, how did you resolve your issue ? @krishnamn